# Each slice or keep the full array

Tags: arrays, ruby

`each_slice` keeps slices of length `n`, but in some cases I want to keep the full array, i.e. do nothing.

```
module MyModule
  def num_slice
    some_boolean_test? ? :full_array : 10 # Note : the content of some_boolean_test? in uninteresting, just assume sometimes it ca return true or false
  end
end

class Foo
  include MyModule

  def a_method
    big_array.each_slice(num_slice) do |array_slice|
      # I want array_slice == big_array if num_slice returns :full_array
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I could write a wrapper around `Array#each_slice` instead so I could define a different behaviour when the parameter is `:full_array`.

Could anyone help with that?

Comment: you just need to let `num_slice = debug_context ? big_array.length  : 10 `

Comment: What does `debug_context?` here represent? Ruby generally discourages "debugging" modes and leans heavily towards writing well-defined unit tests that exercise behaviour in a number of ways to expose bugs before you need to debug them.

Comment: Sorry, `debug_context?` was actually a random name for a boolean method. In my code, I'm actually using `Rails.env.production?`. Renamed.

Comment: Taken literally, `some_boolean_test?` is an undefined method, suggesting you meant it as a stand-in. A stand-in for what? There are no other methods in `MyModule` and `Foo` has only `a_method`.

Comment: `some_boolean_test_we_dont_care_about` was a bit too long to write ^^"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first caution against significant logic differences between environments, since either one branch is less tested or you have twice the code to maintain. But assuming good reasons for the way you're doing it, here are some options:

#### Pass the array

Since `num_slice` is making a decision about the array, it seems reasonable `num_slice` should get access to it.

```
def num_slice(arr)
  some_boolean_test? ? arr.size : 10
end
```

#### Environment configuration

You're using Rails, so you can set the slice size differently in production and your other environments. In production, make it `10`, and in test, make it arbitrarily large; then just use the configured value. This is nice because there's no code difference.

```
def a_method
  big_array.each_slice(Rails.application.config.slice_size) do |array_slice|
    # ...
  end
end
```

#### Wrap it

I wouldn't recommend this method because it causes the most significant difference between your environments, but since you asked about it, here's a way.

```
def a_method
  magic_slice(big_array) do |array_slice|
    # ...
  end
end

def magic_slice(arr, &block)
  if some_boolean_test?
    block.call(arr)
  else
    arr.each_slice(10, &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: The size of a is not known beforehand. And I was hping to define this `num_slice` variable in a different code block which does not have access to the array

Comment: Then set it to `a.count` ?

Comment: I edited my question. num_slice is defined in a different module, and doesn't have access to `a`

Comment: @CyrilDD The design constraints you're putting on yourself seem sort of arbitrary, but I don't have all the context. Hope this new answer helps.

Comment: Thank you, I had tried some stuff on my own and reached something quite similar to what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

```
def a_method(big_array, debug_context)
  num_slice = debug_context ? big_array.length : 10
  big_array.each_slice(num_slice) do |array_slice|
    # array_slice will equal to big_array if debug_context == true
    puts array_slice.inspect
  end
end
```

test:

```
a_method([1,2,3,4,5], true)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer : I am using a method located somewhere else to define this num_slice, and I don't have access to the array in question to get its size.